# Transform an Observable result through a series of Observables

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I want to transform an original value (for example an Object) through multiple functions.

This would be the logic (in synchronous declarative javascript):

```
let origin = {foo: 'bar'}
//where those are functions transforming the original value
let transform = [one, two, three] 

for(let i in transform) {
  origin = transform[i](origin)
}

console.log(origin) //new origin
```

Now, I want to do this:

1. With an Observable origin
2. Where each function returns an Observable

---

At the moment, this is my working code where the transformation array is reduced to transform the previous value:

```
function one(origin) {
  origin.bar = 'foo'
  return origin
}

const transforms = [one]
const origin = {foo: 'bar'}

Observable.of(origin)
.concatMap(origin => {
  return Observable.from(transforms)
  .reduce(function(accumulator, transform) {
    return transform(accumulator)
  }, origin)
  .last()
})
.subscribe(modified => console.log(modified))
//outputs: {bar: 'foo', foo: 'bar'}
```

Here, if I'm using a basic value transformation the `modified` result is the expected one. The thing is, `reduce` does not resolve Observables and using those kind of transformations won't work:

```
//...

function two(origin) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    origin.foobar = origin.foo + origin.bar ? origin.bar : ''
    resolve(origin)
  })
}

function three(origin) {
  return Observable.of(origin)
}

const transforms = [one, two, three]
```

How can I make the above functions to be resolved through the `reduce` operation before applying the next transformation function?

I'm using rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12.

---

I've tried using `expand`, but my Observable emits every transformation:

```
let i = 0

return Observable.of(origin)
.expand(item => {
  if (i > transforms.length -1) {
    return Observable.empty()
  }

  let response = transforms[i](item)

  if (response instanceof Observable || response instanceof Promise) {
    return response
  }

  return Observable.of(response)
})
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is. Could you explicitly state at the top of the question what you are asking?

Comment: I've improve my question

Comment: Assuming each function in `transform` takes a plain value and produces an `Observable` of a type accepted by the next function, I think you want `transform.reduce((obs, f) => obs.concatMap(f), Observable.of(origin))`

Comment: wow thanks, why think complicated when we can think simple...